# Building json path from JQ using some keyword

Tags: json, jq

I have a deep json. Sometimes, I need to look for the json path for a key containing certain word.

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Pod",
    "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": "2019-03-28T21:09:42Z",
        "labels": {
            "bu": "finance",
            "env": "prod"
        },
        "name": "auth",
        "namespace": "default",
        "resourceVersion": "2786",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/auth",
        "uid": "ce73565a-519d-11e9-bcb7-0242ac110009"
    },
    "spec": {
        "containers": [
            {
                "command": [
                    "sleep",
                    "4800"
                ],
                "image": "busybox",
                "imagePullPolicy": "Always",
                "name": "busybox",
                "resources": {},
                "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
                "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
                "volumeMounts": [
                    {
                        "mountPath": "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount",
                        "name": "default-token-dbpcm",
                        "readOnly": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
        "nodeName": "node01",
        "priority": 0,
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "schedulerName": "default-scheduler",
        "securityContext": {},
        "serviceAccount": "default",
        "serviceAccountName": "default",
        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
        "tolerations": [
            {
                "effect": "NoExecute",
                "key": "node.kubernetes.io/not-ready",
                "operator": "Exists",
                "tolerationSeconds": 300
            },
            {
                "effect": "NoExecute",
                "key": "node.kubernetes.io/unreachable",
                "operator": "Exists",
                "tolerationSeconds": 300
            }
        ],
        "volumes": [
            {
                "name": "default-token-dbpcm",
                "secret": {
                    "defaultMode": 420,
                    "secretName": "default-token-dbpcm"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": {
        "conditions": [
            {
                "lastProbeTime": null,
                "lastTransitionTime": "2019-03-28T21:09:42Z",
                "status": "True",
                "type": "Initialized"
            },
            {
                "lastProbeTime": null,
                "lastTransitionTime": "2019-03-28T21:09:50Z",
                "status": "True",
                "type": "Ready"
            },
            {
                "lastProbeTime": null,
                "lastTransitionTime": null,
                "status": "True",
                "type": "ContainersReady"
            },
            {
                "lastProbeTime": null,
                "lastTransitionTime": "2019-03-28T21:09:42Z",
                "status": "True",
                "type": "PodScheduled"
            }
        ],
        "containerStatuses": [
            {
                "containerID": "docker://b5be8275555ad70939401d658bb4e504b52215b70618ad43c2d0d02c35e1ae27",
                "image": "busybox:latest",
                "imageID": "docker-pullable://busybox@sha256:061ca9704a714ee3e8b80523ec720c64f6209ad3f97c0ff7cb9ec7d19f15149f",
                "lastState": {},
                "name": "busybox",
                "ready": true,
                "restartCount": 0,
                "state": {
                    "running": {
                        "startedAt": "2019-03-28T21:09:49Z"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "hostIP": "172.17.0.37",
        "phase": "Running",
        "podIP": "10.32.0.4",
        "qosClass": "BestEffort",
        "startTime": "2019-03-28T21:09:42Z"
    }
}
```

Currently If i need the podIP, then I do that this way to find the object which has the search keyword and then I build the path

```
curl myson | jq "[paths]" | grep "IP" --context=10
```

Is there any nice shortcut to simplify this? What I really need is - all the paths which could have the matching key.

```
spec.podIP
spec.hostIP
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`select` `paths` containing `keyword` in their last element, and use `join(".")` to generate your desired output.

```
paths
| select(.[-1] | type == "string" and contains("keyword"))
| join(".")
```

- `.[-1]` returns the last element of an array,
- `type == "string"` is required because an array index is a number and numbers and strings can't be checked for their containment.

You may want to specify `-r` option.

---

As @JeffMercado implicitly suggested you can set the query from command line without touching the script:

```sh
jq -r 'paths
| select(.[-1] | type == "string" and contains($q))
| join(".")' file.json --arg q 'keyword'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stream the input in, which provides paths and values. You could then inspect the paths and optionally output the values.

```
$ jq --stream --arg pattern 'IP' '
select(length == 2 and any(.[0][] | strings; test($pattern)))
    | "\(.[0] | join(".")): \(.[1])"
' input.json
"status.hostIP: 172.17.0.37"
"status.podIP: 10.32.0.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

shameless plug

https://github.com/TomConlin/json_to_paths

because sometime you do not even know the component you want to filter for before you see what is there.

```sh
json2jqpath.jq file.json 
.
.apiVersion
.kind
.metadata
.metadata|.creationTimestamp
.metadata|.labels
.metadata|.labels|.bu
.metadata|.labels|.env
.metadata|.name
.metadata|.namespace
.metadata|.resourceVersion
.metadata|.selfLink
.metadata|.uid
.spec
.spec|.containers
.spec|.containers|.[]
.spec|.containers|.[]|.command
.spec|.containers|.[]|.command|.[]
.spec|.containers|.[]|.image
.spec|.containers|.[]|.imagePullPolicy
.spec|.containers|.[]|.name
.spec|.containers|.[]|.resources
.spec|.containers|.[]|.terminationMessagePath
.spec|.containers|.[]|.terminationMessagePolicy
.spec|.containers|.[]|.volumeMounts
.spec|.containers|.[]|.volumeMounts|.[]
.spec|.containers|.[]|.volumeMounts|.[]|.mountPath
.spec|.containers|.[]|.volumeMounts|.[]|.name
.spec|.containers|.[]|.volumeMounts|.[]|.readOnly
.spec|.dnsPolicy
.spec|.nodeName
.spec|.priority
.spec|.restartPolicy
.spec|.schedulerName
.spec|.securityContext
.spec|.serviceAccount
.spec|.serviceAccountName
.spec|.terminationGracePeriodSeconds
.spec|.tolerations
.spec|.tolerations|.[]
.spec|.tolerations|.[]|.effect
.spec|.tolerations|.[]|.key
.spec|.tolerations|.[]|.operator
.spec|.tolerations|.[]|.tolerationSeconds
.spec|.volumes
.spec|.volumes|.[]
.spec|.volumes|.[]|.name
.spec|.volumes|.[]|.secret
.spec|.volumes|.[]|.secret|.defaultMode
.spec|.volumes|.[]|.secret|.secretName
.status
.status|.conditions
.status|.conditions|.[]
.status|.conditions|.[]|.lastProbeTime
.status|.conditions|.[]|.lastTransitionTime
.status|.conditions|.[]|.status
.status|.conditions|.[]|.type
.status|.containerStatuses
.status|.containerStatuses|.[]
.status|.containerStatuses|.[]|.containerID
.status|.containerStatuses|.[]|.image
.status|.containerStatuses|.[]|.imageID
.status|.containerStatuses|.[]|.lastState
.status|.containerStatuses|.[]|.name
.status|.containerStatuses|.[]|.ready
.status|.containerStatuses|.[]|.restartCount
.status|.containerStatuses|.[]|.state
.status|.containerStatuses|.[]|.state|.running
.status|.containerStatuses|.[]|.state|.running|.startedAt
.status|.hostIP
.status|.phase
.status|.podIP
.status|.qosClass
.status|.startTime
```